# Restricting amazon s3 access for a web application?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

If a web app uploads data to an amazon s3 bucket is it possible to restrict access to the data for the specific ip address that the web app initiated the upload from and / or can the web app obtain some sort of token that it uses to access the data prior to uploading it?

For example if Hans in Holland uploads `235325.json` and Tina in Germany uploads `3453453.json`, the web application client that Hans is running cannot see Tinas `3453453.json` file and vice versa.  Access to the file upload is only accessible by the user that uploaded it and 100% off access to the rest of the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no way to achieve this natively** (like something you will just configure). 
 You are better off implementing permission control at **application level.**

**But, you can enhance your security mechanisms by generating pre-signed URLs that includes a policy that checks for an IP condition.**

In this case:

1. Hans gets a S3 URL for an object that he uploaded and can legitimately download.
2. Hans sends the S3 URL to Tina via email.
3. Tina tries to open the link.

**The link will fail for Tina since the allowed IP address included in the S3 URL won't match.**

For more information, take a look at [Creating a Signed URL Using a Custom Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-creating-signed-url-custom-policy.html). (Scroll to *"Creating a Policy Statement for a Signed URL That Uses a Custom Policy"*.)

Comment: Note that the document [*Creating a Signed URL Using a Custom Policy*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-creating-signed-url-custom-policy.html) refers to a CloudFront feature, not S3 *per se*, even though the two services can be integrated.  The feature, as currently implemented, only supports IPv4 source addresses.